# How to detect collisions when using Box2D in python mode of Processing?

Tags: java, python, processing, box2d, collision

So in my processing sketch (which is using box2D in python mode) i want two bodies to change color when they collide. I have been following Daniel Shiffman's book The Nature of Code and from that i tried to implement the 'beginContact()' function to accomplish my goal. Here's the code of the function-

```
def beginContact(cp):
    m1=Mover(0,0)
    m2=Mover(0,0)
    a1=Attractor(0,0)
    a2=Attractor(0,0)

    f1=cp.getFixtureA()
    f2=cp.getFixtureB()

    b1=f1.getBody()
    b2=f2.getBody()

    o1=b1.getUserData()
    o2=b2.getUserData()

    if o1.getClass()==Mover.class:
        o1.c=color(255,100,100)
    else:
        o1.c=color(255,255,255)

    if o2.getClass()==Mover.class:
        o2.c=color(255,100,100)
    else:
        o2.c=color(255,255,255)
```

But when i run it, the sketch doesnt detect any collision. It never executes the beginContact function and in the console window i get the following message-

*You are missing the beginContact() method. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jycessing.PAppletJythonDriver.beginContact(org.jbox2d.dynamics.contacts.Contact)
You are missing the endContact() method. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jycessing.PAppletJythonDriver.endContact(org.jbox2d.dynamics.contacts.Contact)*

There are details in the function which might not be clear because they are linked to the other parts of the sketch. But i dont think that that should matter because as is apparent from the above message, the sketch is not able to find the function only.

The thing is that in The Nature of Code book, all examples are in Java mode of Processing. So i think there is some mistake in my implementation of the beginContact function. Interestingly, when i manually converted my entire code in Java and ran it in Java mode, it worked perfectly.

PS- This is my first question and i am new to processing and programming in general, so please help me! My question is probably too lengthy, if so please comment on that. Thanks! ;)

Comment: Try to copy and paste this function at the top of your code just in case. I'm not very good with Python but I noticed that sometimes just the place where the code is written makes a difference with Processing.py

Comment: Just to make myself clear: in several programmin languages, you have to define a function _before_ you can use it. Python is like that.

Comment: @laancelot i tried, no luck.

Comment: I still think that it's a matter of definition, can you show more code (the best would be "working" skeleton code - i.e. minimal code with the same error).